# Can't run pm2 after reinstalling pm2

Tags: bash, debian, command-line

I just uninstalled pm2 by

- Deleting `/usr/bin/pm2` & `/usr/bin/pm2-*`
- Deleting `~/pm2`

Since npm global could not find it to uninstall it.

I have then installed `pm2` using `yarn`: `yarn global add pm2`

I tried using `which` and it obviously pm2 isn't installed in `/usr/bin/pm2` anymore but I'm not sure how to correct this

```bsh
$ which pm2
/home/Syntle/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/pm2
```

Edit: I have made a symlink between `/home/Syntle/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/pm2` and `/usr/bin/pm2` which works but I want to know if there is a better way of doing this, especially if symlinks aren't a great solution here.

Also, using `type` outputs:

```bsh
$ type -a pm2
pm2 is /home/Syntle/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/pm2
pm2 is /home/Syntle/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/pm2
pm2 is /usr/bin/pm2
```

Comment: What is your $PATH? What does `type -a pm2` show?

Comment: I have edited my question and added an explanation about my current solution along with the output of `type -a pm2`. I have also deleted the question from askubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Remove the forest of symlinks you started to create in `/usr/bin`. This directory is a kind of private property of the OS and should stay clean and containing what any upgrade of the OS will maintain.

Here is the correct way to use binaries installed locally with `yarn`:

Edit your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` and add the following lines

```
PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin
# already exported
```

Don't exit your session to test it (it's the suicidal way).
Open another window and type:

```
type pm2
```

next use it.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to `export PATH` -- it's already exported

Comment: You're right. Thank you. This is a case of religious writing :).